# getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Mappings" in a simple maven hibernate project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, annotations

I'm working on a project using maven, hibernate and mysql. This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.heroku.realstate</groupId>
    <artifactId>realstate-database</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and here is my resources/hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$DATABASE_NAME
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            $PASSWORD
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            @USERNAME
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">
            create
        </property>

        <mapping class="com.heroku.realstate.database.user.UserEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.heroku.realstate.database.user.ClientEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.heroku.realstate.database.user.BotEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.heroku.realstate.database.sms.SmsEntity"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have installed mysql and created a database named $DATABASE_NAME but I haven't created any table in database (because I'm not expert in sql and I hope hibernate can do it for people like me!). This is the way I'm using hibernate:

```
class HibernateUtils {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(new File("hibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
    }

    static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

I build this project by maven and it successfully builds. But when I run the application JVM gives me error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Mappings in this line:

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(new File("hibernate.cgf.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
```

What is the problem? How should I fix it? And Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with libraries. You use Hibernate 5. So you don't need this in the `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hibernate 5 uses `hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar` and you don't need to specify it. Because of,  it is a transitive dependency.

You don't need it too, because of you don't use `JPA`

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

There is not `AnnotationConfiguration` in Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5. It is form Hibernate 3!

To configure Hibernate 5

```
 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
  return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(new File("hibernate.cgf.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
```

With:

```
   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Because `Deprecated`. Use the mappings and properties specified in the given application file.

For more info go to [AnnotationConfiguration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html)

Comment: `AnnotationConfiguration` from Hibernate 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Hibernate` above version 3 like builds ***4 or 5***, simply use `Configuration` instead of `AnnotationConfiguration` class because `AnnotationConfiguration` is removed after version 3.

Lets have a snapshot example with 11 dependencies and configuration to use Annotation based mapping configuration.

```
1.  antlr-2.7.7.jar
2.  classmate-1.3.0.jar
3.  dom4j-1.6.1.jar
4.  geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
5.  hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
6.  hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final.jar
7.  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
8.  jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
9.  javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
10. jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
11. mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
```

Configuration file is as follows:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver.class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://zampylob:3306/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hiberuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXXXXXX</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.whodesire.model.Student" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Student POJO class is:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Integer rollNo;

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;

    public Integer getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(Integer rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

and finally the Main Class is :

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

Student student = new Student();
student.setRollNo(1002);
student.setFirstName("Maaherin");
student.setMiddleName("Zubbair");
student.setLastName("Gulfam");
student.setDateOfBirth(new Date());
student.setGender("Male");

session.persist(student);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```